# How to get current model object in Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoalchemy

We stored authenticated user (model of User) using

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    ...
    try:
        current_user = User.query.filter(School_Login.mail == form_mail).first()
        if user.mail == form_mail and user.password == form_pass:
    ...
```

We have a current_user object that referred to authenticated User's properties like current_user.name, current_user.surname.

Here is our data model:

```
class User(db.Document):
    mail = db.StringField()
    pass = db.StringField()
    name = db.StringField()
    ...
```

Here is the problem starts:
We created a user dashboard which shows User's name, surname, etc. We want to access the object which we created in login function which name is current_user but we can't access current_user from user_dashboard function. We've also know that we can't access local variables from function but which point we missed? What is the proper way of accomplish this problem?

```
@app.route('/user-dashboard')
@login_required
def user_dashboard():
    name = current_user.name
    surname = current_user.surname
    return render_template('user-dashboard.html', name=name, surname=surname)
```

We have also looked at application context, bluprints but there is no code example with MongoAlchemy with User authentications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use g.user global in flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617231/how-to-use-g-user-global-in-flask)

Comment: It seems you are using `flask-login`. Did you actually call `login_user` in your login view? Without that you can't use the `current_user` proxy.

Comment: No, I didn't use flask-login extension. I implemented using basic store/pop sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access variables in the same request context, in a different function or class, use the **g** object:

```
from flask import g
g.current_user = ..
....
current_user = g.current_user
```

To do the same but between different requests, you use the **session** dict:

```
from flask import session
session['current_user'] = ...
# Then, whenever you need it:
current_user = session.get('current_user', None)
if current_user is None:
    # maybe redirect to /login
# To remove the user:
session.pop('current_user')
```

Hope this helps..