# Flask-login with multiple users from different machines in Python

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login

I am trying to create a login page which verifies the users directly from an SQL DB. I have used session as below:

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def login():

    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    session['username'] = username
    # db.verify authenticates user from SQL DB
    verifiedUser = db.verifyUser(username, password)
    if verifiedUser:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        global currentUser
        currentUser = session['username']
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        errormsg = "wrong password"
        flash(errormsg)
        print(errormsg)
        return render_template('login.html', error=errormsg)

@app.route('/logout')

def logout():

    # Remove the username from the session if it's there

    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

But with this approach, two users with names "Jack" and "Jill" log in from two different machines, the system overrides and only takes one user.

I have looked at flask-login, but I do not have a user model in my application as I am using an SQL DB directly to verify the username and password. https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Can anyone provide an example or any other to implement sessions to handle multiple users in Python?

Comment: Which database in particular?

Comment: MYSQL Database. I am able to get the table details and verify the user entered in login form from DB but I need help with login for mutliple users at the same time (session management)

Comment: Are you hosting your database on a shared server, or do you have each person making their own database on their own machine?

Comment: Database is hosted on a shared server

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631541/9137276) on how to maintain session and user in flask